# Python: sum of List (recursive function) with starting point p

Tags: python, list, recursion, sum

I got stuck by finding out how to build a recursive function
that sums the elements in a list form a specific starting point
to the end of the list.
for example when list a[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and starting point is Index 5
I want to get the sum of 6+7+8+9+10.
For me it is quite difficult to understand the whole concept of recursive functions. Maybe you can help me to get a step further understanding the concept.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. However, your question is too broad for this site. (Asking for a tutorial on recursive functions is clearly off-topic here, though I realize you were more specific than that.) Please add more context to your question--best would be a code attempt with an explanation of how it is not working. That would also clarify the information that is passed into the desired function, which is not clear from your explanation. Please read and follow the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If the starting index is 5 why do you want to get the sum starting from the index 3?

Comment: if your list is [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and you are starting at index 5 then you are summing 6+7+8+9+10

Comment: and why not simply `sum(yourlist[5:])` - a sum of a list is a very bad use case for recursive computation?

Comment: sorry I meant starting with 6+7+8+9+10

Comment: def maximum(z):
    if len(z) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return z[0] + maximum(z[1:])


print("maximum",maximum(z))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a function that normally computes the sum recursively.
To compute sum of a subsequence of a list, use list slicing.

```
def recsum(num_list):
    if len(num_list) == 0:
        return 0
    return num_list[0] + recsum(num_list[1:])

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

recsum(a)
>>> 15
# It means 1+2+3+4+5

recsum(a[1:])
>>> 14
# It means 2+3+4+5

recsum(a[2:4])
>>> 7
# It means 3+4
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to describe a recursive function in short. Please read the comments carefully.

1. `my_recursive_function` will take the `list` and the `index` from which I want to calculate the sum
2. If the `index==list_length` then I already traversed the list so in this case I shall return 0.
3. If I have not completed traversing the list then I shall take the value of that index call `my_recursive_function` again from the next index. This is where recursion starts.
4. Then return the sum of current `index` and value of next indices.
5. For recursion we should place the recursion braking condition at the first portion of the function.Otherwise it may run infinitely.

   ```
   def my_recursive_sum(my_list, index):

       list_length = len(my_list)

       if index == list_length:  # If i am next to the last element then return 0 and I won't go next and I shall go back

           return 0
       return my_list[index] + my_recursive_sum(my_list, index + 1)  # value of current index+value of next indices.
   a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   result = my_recursive_sum(a, 3)
   print(result)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I interpreted the code delivered by Taohidul Islam:
might be right?

[recursion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQo09.jpg)